# Display multi-value entity reference field in node edit form as draggable?

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

Is there a way to display a multi-value entity reference field as a draggable widget in a node edit form? I'm looking for the exact same behavior that a multi-value image field has by default. I would like a way for the content editor to easily reorder the referenced entities after they have been added via an autocomplete field. I really thought this was core functionality.

Thanks for your help.

I have found this module, but the UI is pretty bad and I really want the same UI that an image field has. https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_dragdrop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the multiple values input in a table format with the draggable option if you choose `Autocomplete` widget for that field under `Manage form display` for that Content type (*not* the `Autocomplete (Tags style)`).

If your field accepts an unlimited number of values the widget will present as one autocomplete input field with a button to `Add another item`. As you add more items you will be able to drag and drop to rearrange the values order.

[image: entity Reference Autocomplete widget Unlimited values]

You can also get that reordering widget with Inline entity form widget (with the additional module Inline entity form).

Comment: Wow, thank you! My field was actually limited to 1 item and I thought I had set it to unlimited. It was core functionality! (face palm)

Comment: It happens sometimes :) I almost dismantled my computer once because the sound wasn't working thinking it must be the sound card, when in fact the speakers weren't plugged in :D

Comment: Is it still possible to (re)order items with the inline entity form widget? As far as I can see, there is no configuration option for that.

Comment: You can reorder within the inline entity widget when adding more than one existing entities. I'm not sure about creating new ones, they don't seem to be rendered within a draggable table.